# Number of slices in a Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a dc2.large Redshift cluster with 4 nodes.
[image]

And according to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html#rs-about-clusters-and-nodes) (see image below), the number of slices per node in a dc2.large cluster are **2**.
[image]

Then why do I see the number of slices as **4** when I run `select * from stv_slices` to determine the number of slices? I am running this using the Admin user.

Why is this the case, and how can I increase the number of slices in my nodes?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output of the Select statement.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Strangely, after resizing my cluster, this is giving me correct results. I don't understand why it wasn't before resizing it. I was on a 4 node cluster while I was checking the number of slices, after changing it to 6, I'm getting 12 slices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use Elastic Resize to change the size of your cluster Redshift moves the existing slices to the new compute nodes so the number of slices per node will change.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/rs-resize-tutorial.html#elastic-resize

Comment: I'm sorry if the question implied that, but I wasn't resizing it, I took the screenshot to show the number of current nodes in my cluster.

Comment: The slices were different because it had already been resized previously with Elastic Resize. To resize again you either chose Classic Resize (which resets the slice counts) or you resized back to the original number of nodes.

Comment: Okay, that explains, but I think what you mean is for the case when one has recently resized a cluster. But this wasn't the case for me, I was using a 4 node cluster, which had I achieved using an elastic resize, since few months, and I was just checking the number of slices before even initiating anything related to resizing. 

Or do you mean the 2 slices per node rule doesn't work when I have resized a node using Elastic-resize, even after few months of the resize operation?

Comment: Basically this is how it went, in case I couldn't make it clear:
1.  2 Nodes -> 4 Nodes using elastic resize
2. Using 4 nodes for few months, never checked number of slices
3. Checks number of slices, finds 4 instead of 8 
4. Posted the question here
5. Resized to 6 nodes, using classic resize, now I'm seeing 12 nodes

Comment: Yes, the effects of Elastic Resize is to change the number of slices per node. This change is never (currently) reverted or altered unless the user does another resize.