# Number of node and slices in Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-redshift

On AWS console I see that the cluster has 2 **ra3.4xlarge** nodes.

[image]

If I do the following query:

```
select tbl, slice, blocknum, id, col, num_values as rows, minvalue, maxvalue
from svv_diskusage
where tbl = 16876453 and col=2
order by slice, blocknum;
```

it show me that there are 14 slices:

[image]

According to these slides https://pages.awscloud.com/rs/112-TZM-766/images/Modernize-your-Data-Warehouse.pdf a ra3.4xlarge contains only 4 slices. Why do I have 14 - 2*4 = 6 more slices?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the IDs given for those 14 slices?  I expect you will see 0-7 as you expect for the data stored on the compute nodes.  You will likely see some very high numbers (above where a cluster could have slices) and these are the slices of the leader node (4) - some system tables are stored on the leader and this storage is not given on the slides you linked.  The other 2 are likely some other "flag" value and/or NULL.  Seeing what you got will help narrow this down.

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for your answer. I add some pictures. I'm analyse an user's table, so it's not possible that it stay on the leader node. The IDs are different.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have only 2 nodes?  The query you ran will only report blocks in use and you only have 29.  If a slice has no blocks in use then that node won't be reported.  So if your cluster is larger than 2, say 4, but there are some slices not in use 14 could be right.  Also I assume that there isn't any cluster resizing or other such activity in flight.  You can look at stv_slices to get the slice to node mapping that can help sort this out

Comment: The AWS console tells me that there are only 2 nodes ( + 1 leader node). The svt_slices tells me that there are two nodes, 0 e 1, and each node has 7 slices. It's maybe possible change the number of slices in a node? In this case from 4 to 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of slices per node is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html

Note that it says

> The number of slices per node might change if the cluster is resized using elastic resize. However the total number of slices on all the compute nodes in the cluster remains the same after elastic resize.

When you use "Elastic Resize" to resize your cluster you end up with fewer or greater slices per node. *This will not affect your performance.* Slices are an internal concept which you generally do not need to worry about.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you for your answer. The note say "the total number of slices on all compute nodes remains the same". But in this case I have 14 slices in total when I should have only 8.

Comment: Your cluster has been resized, possibly across node types. See comments in this previous answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374326/number-of-slices-in-a-redshift-cluster/58382092#58382092

Comment: Yes my cluster has been resized but I don't understand why the number of slices is different to the number of default slices. I thought the the number of slices depends only by the node types. Why the number of slices change if the cluster is resized (meaning change number of nodes of node types)? The number of slices can affect the copy command "The COPY command can load data very efficiently when it loads from multiple files in parallel instead of from a single file. You can split your data into files so that the number of files is a multiple of the number of slices in your cluster."

Comment: How the number of slices is decided after a resized operation?

Comment: Data slices are redistributed to the new nodes (when increasing nodes) or the existing nodes (when decreasing nodes). This allows the resize to complete very quickly. The total slice count does not change until you do a "classic" resize. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-operations.html#classic-resize